# Mobile Chrome Browser behavior when opening link in Google News Website

Tags: javascript, html, css

if you use Chrome Browser (mobile) to open a news link on Google News, a new tab opens, and one can go back to google news by clicking on the "left arrow" below, which is highlighted white, and the user goes back to the google news page. Or there is a small header above, with a "<" char to go back to Gnews.

However, if I try opening an external link written on my webpage with target="_blank" or without it, in Chrome mobile browser, upon opening the link, the arrow below is not highlighted meaning I can't go back to my page.

What is google news doing differently in their html code to be able to insert their own header upon opening an external page, and enable the back browser arrow to go back to the google news page? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is probably using the `History.pushState()` API.

You can learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

Comment: Ok I'll check. Thanks much!

Comment: @falcon356 Please consider marking the answer as correct if it helped you!

Comment: @falcon356 I haven't personally used it. I would consider googling it, maybe